# Can a fitness studio extend a cancelled contract because of lockdown?

Tags: contract-law, germany

I cancelled my contract with a fitness studio in summer 2020. The 6 month cancellation period was due to end in March 2021.

In Germany, fitness studios had to close in November 20 because of Corona. These restrictions were lifted a few weeks ago and I just noticed that the studio has started taking money from my account again. They say that I still have 2 months left on my contract.

What is the situation with a cancelled contract where, during the expiry phase, the supplier cannot deliver on his side of the contract?

Comment: Were you still supposed to pay for those six months and have they effectively stopped taking payments for a period of time during the months they were closed?

Comment: @AsheraH they stopped taking payments during lockdown. I think that I should see that the lockdown suspends everything and the contract resumes unchanged when lockdown is lifted.